# What's a wedding pip?

Tags: british-english, slang

At a wedding, the son of the bride said, "I wish I could have put up a pip for you." What was he talking about?

Comment: Did you find any hints in dictionaries?  Please include your research to help with where you got stuck.

Comment: British and many Commonwealth armies use officer rank insignia that consist of stars and the royal crown. The star is commonly known as a 'pip'. 2nd Lieutenants wear one pip, 1st Lts two, and Captains three. Probably the son is a junior British Army officer and wishes that he could have got a promotion in time for the wedding, or else an officer cadet in training who had hoped to get his commission and start to wear ('put up') (common military expression) his first pip.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is that an answer? If so, please make it one.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - and get a downvote for answering an off-topic question? No thanks.

Comment: The phrase appears to come from *The Charioteer* by Mary Renault. I don't think this is off-topic (although a bit more — actually *any* — evidence of research would be welcome).

Comment: Yes. Even the title and author would have been good. A novel set during World War 2. The son appears to have recently finished public school and is probably awaiting call-up into the army.